# Will Android http library download the certificate while making https request?

Tags: android, ios, ssl, cross-domain

It can be a dumb question, but I could not find any proper resource which clearly states this. In case of browser making an https call, it would have downloaded the certificate from the domain already. How does it work for a mobile application? Does Android/iOS http library automatically download the certificate?

Comment: *"...whereas in case of cross domain requests, certificate download does not happen."* - I have no idea what you are trying to say with this but it might wrong. The certificate of the server is always transferred to the client inside each full TLS handshake, no matter if cross domain or not. And a full handshake is always done if no session resumption is done - which would require a previous full handshake. Also, pinning has nothing to do with this.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich thanks for the comment. https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/05/25/cross-domain-ajax-with-cross-origin-resource-sharing/ is my source for that statement.

Comment: This source is not talking about getting the certificate from the server at all. While I don't know exactly which part of this source you got wrong my guess is that it was *"By default, cross-origin requests do not provide credentials (cookies, HTTP authentication, and client-side SSL certificates)"*. But this talks about **client-side** certificates, i.e. certificates send for authentication from the client to the server and not about the usual server certificates. Note that client certificates are only used if the server requests these explicitly in the first place, i.e. they are rarely used

Comment: spot on @SteffenUllrich thanks for giving the details. With your permission let me update the question.

Comment: You don't need my permission to update the question, just edit it. No harm will be done by doing this since there are no answers to this question yet.